# If a column contains a word, then generate a new column with the value found

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to clean my df['Country'] variable by creating a new one df['Country Clean'] that takes the value of the country variable if it finds it in the df['Country'] column.

I figured out though that if I repeat my command, I will also delete my previous findings and i will only get a variable reporting the finding for 'Russia'

Is there a way to do this?

```
data = {'Number':['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2'], 'Country':['Italy 1', 'Italie', 'Ecco', 'Russia is in Euroasia' ,  'Yugoslavia', 'Russia']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df['Country Clean'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'(^.*Italy.*$)', 'Italy')
df['Country Clean']  = df['Country'].str.replace(r'(^.*Russia.*$)', 'Russia')
```

Expected output

```
data2 = {'Number':['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2'], 'Country':['Italy', 'Italy', NaN, 'Russia' , NaN , 'Russia']}
exp = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
exp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first normalizing the country names and then change the Country Clean column values according to the allowed country list:

```
normalize_countries={"Italie": "Italy", "Rusia": "Russia"}    # Spelling corrections
pattern = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(normalize_countries)) # Regex to find misspellings

countries = ["Italy", "Russia"]                               # Country list
df['Country Clean'] = df['Country'].str.replace(pattern, lambda x: normalize_countries[x.group()])
def applyFunc(s):  
    for e in countries:
        if e in s:
            return e
    return 'NaN'

df['Country Clean'] = df['Country Clean'].apply(applyFunc)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Number                Country Country Clean
0      1                Italy 1         Italy
1      2                 Italie         Italy
2      1                   Ecco           NaN
3      2  Russia is in Euroasia        Russia
4      1             Yugoslavia           NaN
5      2                 Russia        Russia
```

The `df['Country'].str.replace(pattern, lambda x: normalize_countries[x.group()])` line searches for all misspelt country names as whole words in the `Country` column and replaces them with correct spelling variants.

You may also add whole word check when searching for countries if you use regexps in the `countries` list and then use `re.search` instead of `if e in countries` in the `applyFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
In [15]: countries = ["italy", "russia", "yugoslavia", "italie"]

In [16]: for i in countries:df.loc[lambda x:x.Country.str.lower().str.contains(i), 'Country Clean'] = i.capitalize()

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
  Number                Country Country Clean
0      1                Italy 1         Italy
1      2                 Italie        Italie
2      1                   Ecco           NaN
3      2  Russia is in Euroasia        Russia
4      1             Yugoslavia    Yugoslavia
5      2                 Russia        Russia
```

Comment: That's awesome. how can I catch 'Italie' though?

Comment: If you do not have too many variations for the `countries`, then you can include 'italie' in the `countries` list. This will spare you the usage of Regex. However, if there are too many variations, then regex is the only way.